# Node.js javascript to connect webhosting mysql database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, web-hosting

I have tried to use Node.js to connect to my webhosting mysql database with the code below.

```
var request = require('request');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection(
    {
      host     : 'mysql.hostinger.my',
      user     : 'xxxxx',
      password : 'xxxxx',
      database : 'xxxxx',
    }
);
```

But I have failed to connect it. Following are the error messages I get.
[image]

Anyone can tell me what's the problem here? is the way to connect is not correct? Thanks.

Comment: your address was not connect

Comment: try to connect your localhost first